# Нужная ли запятая после слова "обратно"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, тире-или-двоеточие

"Он улетел обратно, на другую планету. Все вскоре улетают".

Answer (score 2):

Запятую и даже тире здесь можно оправдать правилом об уточняющих членах предложения (см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118)).

> Обособляются (выделяются запятыми, реже — тире) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов (уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому). Чаще всего уточняются обстоятельства и определения.
>
> 1. Уточняющие обстоятельства места: *Там, ниже, мох тощий, кустарник седой (П.); Внизу, в тени, шумел Дунай (Тютч.); Илья Ильич учился в Верхлёве, верстах в пяти от Обломовки, у тамошнего управляющего немца Штольца (Гонч.).* <...>

В вашем случае "на другую планету" можно счесть за уточняющее обстоятельство места (улетел обратно (куда?) — на другую планету), поэтому корректно выделить его **запятой** или **тире**.

Впрочем, тут можно поставить и **двоеточие** (см. [здесь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=150,6)).

> 1. Между частями бессоюзного сложного предложения ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть (одно или несколько предложений) раскрывает содержание первой части (между частями можно вставить слова *а именно*): *Погода была ужасная: ветер выл, мокрый снег падал хлопьями (П.); Страшная мысль мелькнула в уме моем: я вообразил её в руках разбойников (П.); Дубровский приставил фитиль, выстрел был удачен: одному оторвало голову, двое были ранены (П.).* <...>

В вашем случае вторая часть раскрывает содержание первой (улетел обратно (а именно): на другую планету).

Наконец, допускается вообще ничего не ставить, считая "обратно на другую планету" единым обстоятельством места. В "Нацкорпусе" есть множество соответствующих примеров (см. [здесь](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&ct=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE)).

**ВЫВОД**

Таким образом, вы можете выбрать сами, какой из перечисленных знаков ставить (запятую, тире, двоеточие) и ставить ли вообще. Любой из этих вариантов допустим, так что опирайтесь на контекст — что лучше подойдёт по смыслу.

*Он улетел обратно, на другую планету. Все вскоре улетают.*

*Он улетел обратно — на другую планету. Все вскоре улетают.*

*Он улетел обратно: на другую планету. Все вскоре улетают.*

*Он улетел обратно на другую планету. Все вскоре улетают.*